# meaning of subspace topology induced from R

Tags: general-topology

For below exerpt, I just don't quite catch what it means for "**with the subspace topology induced from R**". As I am not a native English speaker, so this puzzles me, or the math puzzles me, and I don't know which, maybe both.

Corollary 1.3.11 A set is closed if and only if it contains its boundary.
Definition 1.3.12 Let $A$ be a subset of a space $X$. A point $a \in A$ is called isolated if $a \notin A^{\prime}$. The set $A$ is called perfect if it is closed and has no isolated points.

Example 1.3.12 Consider the closed unit interval $I$ **with the subspace topology induced from $\mathbb{R}$**. Let $J_1=\left(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}\right), J_2=\left(\frac{1}{9}, \frac{2}{9}\right) \cup\left(\frac{7}{9}, \frac{8}{9}\right), \ldots$. Notice that $J_n, n>1$, is the union of $2^{n-1}$ intervals of the form $\left(\frac{1+3 k}{3^n}, \frac{2+3 k}{3^n}\right)$ which are contained in $I-\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} J_i$. The Cantor set is defined by $C=I-\bigcup_1^{\infty} J_n$. This is the set of all points in $I$ whose at least one triadic expansion (base 3 ) contains no 1 's. We observe that $C$ is perfect. Clearly, $C$ is closed. To see that every point of $C$ is a limit point, let $x \in C$ be arbitrary and $U$ be an open interval containing $x$. Choose a sufficiently large integer $n$ so that $U$ contains a closed interval $\left[x-1 / 3^n, x+1 / 3^n\right]$. Now, find an integer $k \geq 0$ such that $x$ belongs to a closed interval of the form $\left[k / 3^n,(k+1) / 3^n\right]$. Obviously, one end point of this interval is different from $x$. Thus $U$ contains a point of $C$ other than $x$, and $x$ is a limit point of $C$.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it what is the topology on $I$ that they consider?

Comment: If $R$ is a topological space and $X\subset R$ then the subspace topology on $X$ induced from $R$ is the topology on $X$ whose open sets are those of the form $U\cap X$ where $U$ is an open subset of $R$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: See [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology).